# The input tag not showing in the form spring-mvc-form

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

So i'm trying to create a from for adding products but when i go to the url the form doesn't show any input tag only the labels

I followed this documentation : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-form-tutorial

this is the GET method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/product", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView showForm() {
return new ModelAndView("products/CreateProduct", "produit", new Produit());
}
```

and this is the POST method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/create-product", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitproduct(@Valid @ModelAttribute("produit")Produit produit, 
  BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {
if (result.hasErrors()) {
    return "error";
}
model.addAttribute("productID", produit.getId_produit());
model.addAttribute("productName", produit.getNom_produit());
model.addAttribute("productPrice", produit.getPrix_produit());
model.addAttribute("productDescription", produit.getDescription_produit());
model.addAttribute("productBrand", produit.getMarque_produit());
model.addAttribute("productBarCode", produit.getCodeBarre_produit());
return "products/CreateProduct";
}
```

[image: trying to add a product]

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I also have the same problem. So frustrated. It should be a very basic function.